# To find $P(XY>z)$ for $\operatorname{Pareto}(a)$ IIDs $X,\,Y$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d $\operatorname{Pareto}(a)$, i.e. each of them has PDF $f(x)=ax^{-a-1}1_{[1,\,\infty)}(x)$ for some $a>0$. Calculate $P(XY>z)$ for $z\ge1$.

I tried converting from Pareto distribution to exponential such that $P(\ln X+\ln Y>\ln z)$

But don't know what to do further.

What I can infer is that it is essentially P((gamma(2,alpha)>log Z).
However how do I calculate the same...in order to obtain a closed form.
I would kindly ask for an answer in order to enable me to understand as I am unable to evaluate the expression using the CDF of the gamma distribution.

Hope my argument is clear.

Comment: Do you know the sum of two $\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$ IIDs is distributed? Failing that, which methods do you know for computing the distribution of the sum of IIDs?

Comment: Well it is given that the Paretos are i.i.d distributed now..I know that log(Pareto) is exponential so I transformed it to P(X_1+Y_1>=logZ) where X_1 and Y_1 are exponetially.

Comment: I have an idea...that sum of exponetially distributed i.i.ds follow gamma distribution.

Comment: And thank you for editing the question @J.G...thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. You can prove your Gamma-distribution claim with convolutions or characteristic functions (or, which is similar, moment-generating functions). If we know which methods are allowed at your level, we can help you.

Comment: Ya,that has been discussed in our course..however I have a question that the problem essentially reduces to P(Gamma(alpha,2))>logZ..

Comment: That's what it reduces to, yes. Make sure any course details you clarify are edited into the question, rather than placed in comments, which are ideally ephemeral.

Comment: I have added the issue at which I am stuck at in the main question body ....@J.G.

Answer (score 1):

Since as you've realized $W:=\ln(XY)$ has PDF $a^2we^{-2aw}1_{[0,\,\infty)}(w)$,$$P(W>\ln z)\stackrel{t:=2aw}{=}\frac12a\int_{2a\ln z}^\infty\frac12ate^{-t}dt=[(-1-t)e^{-t}]_{2a\ln z}^\infty,$$which I leave you to simplify.

Comment: I did not quite understand the  1st line...the PDF mentioned by you in the answer it is which distribution PDF.

Comment: I am actually unable to connect whether that is the PDF of the Gamma distribution...as I knew it in a different form @J.G.

Comment: @Mathtome Edit your knowledge of the Gamma distribution of $\ln X+\ln Y$ into the question.